# How much do health globes heal

Tags: diablo-iii

Health Globes or Orbs are dropped from killed monsters or spawn in some locations.

How much do they heal, is it a set amount or a percentage, and are there any other mechanics, like buffs, de-buffs that change the amount healed.

I would appreciate an formula if one is available.

Comment: Notable tip: Champions spawn a large healing globe when they hit 50% health, and upon death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, I have seen two different types of health globe, each healing a different amount. The percentage healed is not fixed either. It differs slightly from globe to globe.

- **Small**: Heals for about 18-20%. Dropped by normal monsters mostly.
- **Large**: Heals for about 33-35%. Dropped by champions and uniques mostly.

I have yet seen anything bigger than a large.

Note that I had no bonus to the amount healed by globes at the time of testing, so these figures should be very close to the real figures.

Answer (score 2):

As of the end of the beta, [they healed 15% of your max health](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Health_Globe).  I assume it hasn't changed at this point.

Comment: are there any other mechanics, like buffs, de-buffs that change the amount healed?

Comment: There are items that can increase the amount of health they give though... some stat like: "+44 health from health globes" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

While an older source, the [Diablowiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Health_Globe) site has some good references from development plans for health orbs.

The intent was to have a variety of different strength orbs in game, ranging from 15% to a rumored 100% (the following was on the official Diablo 3 website before they took down the game guide for revamping):

> More powerful health globes, capable of completely restoring your health even at death's door, might exist somewhere in the world of Sanctuary. Of course, that's probably wishful thinking.

During a demonstration of the still-in-development PvP Arena system during Blizzcon 2010, the health globes that spawned provided a 40% heal.

In addition to the variable strength of the orbs, there are item modifiers that provide a direct increase of the amount healed.  The amount provided varies widely, and scales with item level.

Some examples I have seen are a level 10 rare item that provided +40 life from health globes, a level 8 rare item that provided +28 life from health globes, and a normal level 10 magic item that provided +17 health from health globes.