# How close do you have to be to your party member(s) to heal them with a health orb?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have seen [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66277/how-much-do-health-globes-heal) but it did not answer my question.

While fingering through the achievement list, I noticed the **Life is Beautiful** achievement:

[image]

Seeing as the description mentions that you can heal other players by picking up health orbs, **How close does the party member(s) have to be to you to receive that heal from an orb you pick up?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The party members don't actually have to be that close at all. The orbs that are displayed will apply health to everyone when the orb is picked up by anyone in the vicinity. This is probably why the required amount for this achievement is ridiculously high.  [This](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3888482652) thread has a similar discussion.

***05/17/12*** - Last night my girlfriend and I did a little bit of testing, and we found that even someone standing pretty far off of the minimap view can still get the globe heal. I believe the shrine buff range is the same as health globes.

As far as the **actual** distance from the player is concerned it might be pretty hard to test.

Comment: Shrines, I know, are different as you do have to be really close to  get it as I have been around the corner from my buddy and did not receive the shrine.